# PHP CodeIgniter Session ID not regenerating

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm having problems with the session ID not regenerating. This is my config

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 60; // 15 minutes
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30; // 5 minutes
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

I set it to really short timeframes for experimentation. When I register a user, I set a session variable called user_id then load a different page. At registration the output for session variables is

```
[code]session_id() = kvrphe8... 
timestamp (from ci_sessions) = 1523413499
user_id = user87B...
```

If i wait exactly 40 seconds then query these same variables via ajax (without reloading the page), I get

```
session_id() = kvrphe8... 
timestamp (from ci_sessions) = 1523413499
user_id =user87B...
```

Why isn't the session id regenerating after 30 seconds? If i wait more than 60 seconds the session is destroyed as expected, and the session_id() changes. But shouldn't it change every 30 seconds in this instance? I would also expect the session to be destroyed at 30 seconds because sess_regenerate_destroy = TRUE, but that obviously isnt happening either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('session');

if (($this->userdata['last_activity']+30) >= $this->now)
{
 $this->session->sess_regenerate();
}
```

You have to regenerate using the above function.

Calling session_id() means just get the session id not regenerating.

Comment: that's not what the documentation says from what I can tell. From CodeIgniter documentation: sess_time_to_update "This option controls how often the session class will regenerate itself and create a new session ID. Setting it to 0 will disable session ID regeneration." . To me that's clearly saying after 30 seconds it should regenerate. And $this->session->sess_update() is not a function i tried it

Comment: you have to load the library session.

Comment: The library is autoloaded, Must it be working if I set and retrieved session variables? I think you're referring to CodeIgniter 2. In CodeIgniter 3 sess_update is no longer a function I believe.

Comment: try sess_regenerate

Comment: That works to regenerate the session id indeed. So you're saying that despite what it says in CodeIgniter docs sess_time_to_update and sess_regenerate_destroy config variables are totally useless

Comment: you can try to see if any function altered the sess_time_to_update in your original config.

Comment: With `$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30;` the session id will (except during AJAX request) regenerate after the set duration *when the class is loaded*. Note the phrase - "when the class is loaded". It's not going to "know" it should regenerate until a page is requested that loads the session class.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is because CodeIgniter does not regenerate sessions during AJAX server requests.

This makes sense because the page currently in the browser is not being "reloaded" which would be required if the session id were to change. Changing the session id would mean the session cookie sent when the page was loaded would no longer be valid.

Check out the class constructor in `system/Session.php` and you'll see (right after the call to `session_start();` that session regeneration is not done when ajax requests are being made.

Comment: You might want to consider changing `$config['sess_regenerate_destroy']` to FALSE. Read the **Warning** [on this page](http://si1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) for the reasons why.

Comment: Ah thank you for your answer that makes some sense. I have noticed though that If I call $this->session->sess_regenerate in ajax calls and make consecutive ajax calls, the session id is regenerated and session variables like user_id are not lost, which suggests to me that regenerating the session id in ajax calls does not render the session cookie useless, it works as you would hope it to work. So why would CodeIgniter not do that automatically on an Ajax call?

Comment: and just to correct myself I did not read sess_regenerate_destroy doc correctly. That will destroy OLD session data whenever a session is regenerated if set to TRUE, not current session data. This keeps old session items in the table from building up, and i definitely want this in my case

Comment: As I understand it, when `sess_regenerate_destroy === TRUE` what happens is a new session file (or database record if you're using that driver) that holds the session data is created. It is filled with the stored session data and then the old file (or db record) is destroyed. When `sess_regenerate_destroy === FALSE` the existing file (or db record) is simply associated with the new session id. Whether `sess_regenerate_destroy` is true or false the user data is maintained.